# CSS3 :empty pseudo class

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-selectors

I'm new and i have a question about CSS3 and :empty pseudo-class.

I create a web ajax application. In my page layout I've got a sidebar and i want to hide this if is empty. So i wrote:

```
#my_sidebar:empty { display:none;}
```

For display it when isn't empty i wrote

```
#my_sidebar:not(:empty) { display:block; }
```

This is working but with chrome the sidebar appear only after one click on the page or on a link. Why?
Can someone help me?

Thanks! (excuse me for my terryfing english!!)

EDIT:
the html page:

```
    <body id='body'>

<!-- Header -->
<header id="top" class="cf">
    <div id="branding">
        <h1><a href=" " onClick="presenter.homepage()">Project Management</a></h1>
    </div>
    <nav id="nav-user">
        <ul>
          <li><a id="user" href="profilo"><span id="username"></span><img id="avatar" class="avatar"></a></li>
          <li><a id="company" href="azienda">Azienda</a></li>
          <li><a id="logout" href="logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="nav-main">
        <ul class="cf">
         <li>
            <button id="back" onClick="javascript: history.back();" href="#" />&larr;</button></li>
        </ul>
       <!--popup con task finiti -->
        <div id="task-ended" class="cf">
          <div class="triangle-border top">
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

    </div><!--task-ended-->
    <!--popup con task finiti -->
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- Main Body -->
<div id="container" class="cf">
    <div id="loading" style="display:none"><img src="images/loading.gif" /></div>
    <div id="my_sidebar" class="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main" class="main"></div>
</div>
<footer class="cf" id="footer">

Mentis Project Management 
</footer>
</body>
```

and css:

```
.sidebar {
 float:right;
 width: 36%;
 text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: We need to see more code, or even your page.

Comment: Well, Chrome has at least [*one* problem with the `:empty` pseudo selector](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88906).

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/WUJ3b/ seems to be working.  Even in chrome

Comment: but if i add dinamically an element it isn't work (in my case work only after a click of mouse)
http://jsfiddle.net/2BFLa/

Comment: in some browsers the css attribute: "display" has to be set manually from the html markup such as: <div style="display:block"> at first. May try this: <div id="my_sidebar" class="sidebar" style="display:none">.

Comment: @F.Müller: if i write display:block the sidebar always appear, also if is empty.. Otherwise, with display:none the sidebar never appear... i think that when i add an element to sidebar i set .css('style', 'block') manually..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chrome bug apparently only happens with the `display` property, so you can instead set `visibility: hidden;` to make it invisible and `position: absolute;` to prevent the space from being reserved. This doesn't require the use of `:not(:empty)`.

As always, whenever you find yourself pushing browsers to their limits, stop and ask yourself if there's a simpler way to do the job. Depending on what you need, simple calls to jQuery's `show()` and `hide()` method could work just as well. :)